# Is this question relevant for Poker.se? Are the comments better suited to Meta?

Tags: discussion

Re: [What was the fifth card of the dead man's hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/922/what-was-the-fifth-card-of-the-dead-mans-hand)

I'd like to hear a little discussion on this before I take any mod actions. I feel as if it's one of those borderline issues, although it's not of huge concern.

My quick thoughts:

- The question is poker related, although it's historical and not technical in nature. Not that that matters. It's just an observation.
- The comments are probably Meta material, but it's open to discussion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm the asker, I want to say something. Please don't take it an offensive.

I asked the question ans answer it also, [there is nothing wrong about it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Our site is beta now. So there is no directly point to where this site should go. [Users](https://poker.stackexchange.com/users) will dedice it. But I hope, this site wil grow up quickly and will became of the best poker guides on the internet.

Let's discuss on your topic:

> The question is poker related, although it's historical and not
>   technical in nature. Not that that matters. It's just an observation.

Yep, this is historical one. But since Stackoverflow was found, there are a lot of question asked about *history of programming* in SO. 1960s, 1970s. Even there are some questions about *first computer programmers' quote*. Dead man's hand is an interesting event in poker history. IMO, there is nothing **wrong** to ask it here.

What if someone search this on Google and find this question usefull? Still will be irrelevant? Every question and answer in SE sites are not for only their users, they are there for the all internet users.

Said again, Please don't take it an offensive. These are just mine humble opinions. Please join this discussion for finding the right results.